# How to handle a payment error . And return the subscription to its original stay in the stripe-payments?

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I have a problem with a python "stripe-payments".

I'm trying to understand why with the help of a card, you can increase the quantity without having money on a bank card.

I wrote an example code for the user to which I linked the card 4000000000000341
if you use this code first everything will work well and the payment will not pass. If you run it a second time, the payment will already pass.

I understand this is due to the fact that I did not reset the Subscription using stripe.Subscription.modify.

But I don't understand how to do it, or I don't understand what to do at all.
What am I doing wrong? What should I add to the code so that when the script is run again, the stripe.Invoice.create(api_key, customer="cus_JvhLMsllZSYZjQ").pay() command fails, and "quantity" is old_quantity.

```
import stripe
from stripe.error import CardError
new_quantity = 49
old_quantity = 48

new_plan_id = 'plan_EytNKdIq7pTkD7'
tax_rates = None
api_key = 'sk_test_i8lHZRJjHKnkfjtyjytj'
stripe_id = 'sub_JvhLIfdgqiMb06'

stripe_obj = stripe.Subscription.retrieve( stripe_id, api_key=api_key )
old_items = [{'id': x.id, 'deleted': True} for x in stripe_obj['items']['data']]

stripe.Subscription.modify(
    stripe_id,
    items=old_items + [{'plan': new_plan_id, 'quantity': new_quantity, "tax_rates":tax_rates}],
    api_key=api_key
)

inv=stripe.Invoice.create(api_key, customer="cus_JvhLMsllZSYZjQ")

try:
    
    res = inv.pay()
    print("payment successful")
except CardError as e:
    inv.void_invoice()

    # here I am trying to reset the Subscription to the initial state.
    stripe_obj = stripe.Subscription.retrieve(stripe_id, api_key=api_key)
    old_items = [{'id': x.id, 'deleted': True} for x in stripe_obj['items']['data']]
    stripe.Subscription.modify(
    stripe_id,
    items=old_items + [{'plan': new_plan_id, 'quantity': old_quantity, "tax_rates":tax_rates}],
    api_key=api_key
    )

   stripe.Subscription.retrieve(stripe_id, api_key=api_key)

   print("payment failed")
```

Comment: Can you clarify - are you trying to make it so when a Subscription update payment fails, the subscription reverts back to it's state before the update request?

Comment: yes.  the subscription should return to its state before the update request